# h2o numeric columns are converted to enum

Tags: python, h2o

i have parquet file that is consisted with both numeric and categorical columns.

i want to create a GBM model that later on i can implement it's mojo in java program for inference.
the problem is that until now i imputed the nulls in the data as 0 for numeric and "EMPTY" for categorical columns.

when i am doing it in h2o i can enforce my scheme in h2o import_file with col_types parameter.

when i don't use the imputation , and let h2o impute by itself - it transform my numeric columns to enum type.

if i try to enforce the types on import without my imputation i get the following error for all numeric features:

```
 error = 'Unsupported type override (String -> Numeric). Column XXX will be parsed as String'
```

so continuous features will not get the right treatment...why it is converted to enum?
how can i avoid this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2O should recognize the datatypes of parquet files and set them beforehand. You may have the numeric columns set as strings/categorical when saving the parquet files. What do you have the parquet file saving the column datatypes as?

I verified on on H2O 3.30.0.1 that data types will be recognized by what the parquet files defines them as. See below.

#### Create numeric column (`sepal_len`) with a missing value from iris dataset

```
#Read a dataset
iris = h2o.import_file("http://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/iris/iris_wheader.csv")
#Convert one value to None
iris[0, 0] = None
#Make it as pandas df and save as parquet as 
df = iris.as_data_frame()
df.to_parquet('iris.parquet')
df.dtypes
```

Returns:

```
sepal_len    float64
sepal_wid    float64
petal_len    float64
petal_wid    float64
class         object
dtype: object
```

^columns are floats

```
#Read in h2o
iris2 = h2o.import_file('iris.parquet')
iris2.head(2)
```

Returns:

```
sepal_len   sepal_wid   petal_len   petal_wid   class
nan         3.5         1.4         0.2         Iris-setosa
4.9         3           1.4         0.2.        Iris-setosa
```

#### Check datatypes remain same from definition from parquet (made in pandas)

```
iris2.types
```

Returns:

```
{'sepal_len': 'real',
 'sepal_wid': 'real',
 'petal_len': 'real',
 'petal_wid': 'real',
 'class': 'enum'}
```

^H2O frame data types are real (not enum)

#### Change pandas dataframe to `str` column and save as a new parquet file:

```
#Save the parquet as a string column
df.astype({'sepal_len':'str'}).to_parquet('irisB.parquet')
#Read file again
irisB = h2o.import_file('irisB.parquet')
irisB.types
```

Returns:

```
{'sepal_len': 'enum',
 'sepal_wid': 'real',
 'petal_len': 'real',
 'petal_wid': 'real',
 'class': 'enum'}
```